# Gitlab Project tags and Runner tags; are they related?

Tags: tags, gitlab

I have specified tag `docker` for group runner and I've specified tag `docker` in Project `general` settings.
Does that make sure to build project in the specified runner only!

There is no clear documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab [runner tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/#using-tags) (made for selecting the right jobs) are not related to [Project tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/university/training/topics/tags.html) (made for releases) or even [Project labels](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/labels.html) (for MR and issues).

The term tags is likely to actually refer to label ([issue 36772](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/36772)), and those labels were only recently more visible ([issue 2978](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2978) and [issue 44704](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/44704), for GitLab 11.3)